# The Great Kilo-Question

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, we reached 1000 questions! We've been around for 4 months and have generated a lot of really great content. We're well on the way to Making the Internet a Better Place.

So, let's have a bit of a celebration. Let's have a look back at some of the best stuff we've generated. Comment suggestions for categories of question; answer with specific questions, the category you put them in, and we'll show off the best of us.

### Categories

- In-universe
- Science based
- Magic based

Comment: [In-universe questions](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1213/328), though [controversial](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/363/328) are interesting. There's also [this recent question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/9117/328) that I really liked which feels similar but isn't really. [This answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/9120/328) definitely added to the appeal of the question.

Comment: @overactor What do you mean by in-universe?

Answer (score 4):

A few personal favorites:

1. [How might modern humans leave a message for 50,000 years?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/how-might-modern-humans-leave-a-message-for-50-000-years/3482#3482)
2. [How could dragons be explained without magic?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-could-dragons-be-explained-without-magic/345#345)
3. [A small group recreating modern technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/6747/a-small-group-recreating-modern-technology/6774#6774)

Comment: I wrote a semi-crappy answer to the last question (A small group recreating modern technology), but most of the other answers there were really good. I think that exemplifies the creativity that we have on this site.

Answer (score 3):

For me one of the best questions has been [how would having multiple moons affect tides?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-would-having-multiple-moons-affect-tides). I really enjoyed thinking through and working out the answer to that one.

I think it's simple, very useful and could be used by WBers time and time again!

Answer (score 2):

I like this question because the answers covered just about everything:

- [Where in the solar system is the most viable place to put my colonists, after Mars and Luna?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/where-in-the-solar-system-is-the-most-viable-place-to-put-my-colonists-after-ma)

This question provided a lot of creative answers, and was what drew me to the site:

- [How do I drug a population in the most efficient way?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/843/how-do-i-drug-a-population-in-the-most-efficient-way)